# Mod-Rewrite for large sites...how much is too much?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a huge site with lots of different functionality...and I really want to have beautiful url's throughout. The problem is that my Mod-Rewrite has become a monster of its own...most of the sections have different URL needs, directory depths, etc.

How many rules are too much? and what is normal?

Is it better to simply mod-rewrite the main structural parts of the url, and then just tack on $_GET values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best is if your application does the URL parsing and mod_rewrite is only responsible for routing the requests to your application. That will keep your rules to a minimum and keep the responsibility to your application since your application should know best what the URLs mean.